# maxinactiveinterval for some session attributes only

Tags: java, httpsession

I need to call `maxinactiveinterval` for http session for some transaction purpose. But i need to implement timeout only for some attributes and al other attributes like user login stuff has to persist. Is there a way to set timeout for some attributes only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the last access time along with the attribute and when you use the attribute, first check if it is not too old.

Create a wrapper class for it, something like:

```
class AttrWrapper<T extends Serializable> {
    public final T value;
    public final long timeoutMs;
    private long lastAccess = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public AttrWrapper(T value, long timeoutMs) {
        this.value = value;
        this.timeoutMs = timeoutMs;
    }
    public boolean isValid() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - lastAccess > timeoutMs)
            return false;
        lastAccess = now;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And store it like this:

```
// 1 minute timeout:
session.setAttribute("myattr", new AttrWrapper<>("This is the value", 60*1000));
```

And access it like this:

```
AttrWrapper<?> attr = (AttrWrapper<?>) session.getAttribute("myattr");
if (attr != null) {
    if (attr.isValid()) {
        // Attribute is valid, you can use it
    } 
    else {
        // Attribute is invalid, timed out, remove it
        session.removeAttribute("myattr");
    }
}
```

You can even create a helper, utility method for this so you don't have to repeat code:

```
public static <T extends Serializable> T getAttr(String name, HttpSession sess) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    AttrWrapper<T> attr = (AttrWrapper<T>) sess.getAttribute("myattr");
    if (attr == null)
        return null;
    if (attr.isValid())
        return attr.value; // Attribute is valid, you can use it

    // Attribute is invalid, timed out, remove it
    sess.removeAttribute("myattr");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is right , but i want to setmaxlifetime , because i want to do something, like release some LOCK when the session timeout. Release lock has to do even if the user idle or close window ehatever. So i cant implement as what you said. For this scenario i made a class which implement HttpSessionListener and inside sessionDestroyed method i want to destroy only one attribute and set other attributes  to new session. How can i do this? Thanks for your reply and obviously i wil upvote for this.

Comment: You can use this solution in combination with a `HttpSessionListener` to release locks if a session indeed times out.